# Aligment of Dynamically added columns in RadGridView

Tags: wpf, telerik-grid, radgridview

I need to right align some dynamically added columns.
For RadGridView I have used the following code

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="radGridView" ShowGroupPanel="False"
     AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportTable, Mode=TwoWay}" 
     IsFilteringAllowed="True"  GridLinesVisibility="Both"
     AlternateRowBackground="#FFE5E5E5" 
     AlternationCount="2"  EditTriggers="None" 
     telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8"
     Margin="0,10,-7,-175" Height="339" Width="1337"/>
```

As a ItemsSource I have bind the DataTable to the RadGridView.
I don't want to align all columns to the right, only need to align some columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution for the alignment of columns. For this you required the object of .xaml where you have declared the RadGridView and you can directly align the columns

```
  for (int loop = 2; loop < cur_scrn.radGridView.Columns.Count; loop++)
        {
            cur_scrn.radGridView.Columns[loop].TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
        }
```

Here cur_scrn is .xaml object and radGridView is the name of RadGridView control.I have started the loop from 2 as I need to right align all other columns than 0th and 1st